# Magento 1.9- Order not placed using SagePay

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, checkout-page, error-message

I am getting an error while try to place order using Sagepay payment method. When I click Order Place button, an alert message is showing. Like:

Can't load serializer adapter "Phpserialize".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem for older Sage Pay Suite Pro versions. On 4.2.16 and forward you should not experience this problem anymore.

Kind Regards,
Santiago.

Comment: How to update to new version?

Comment: email sagepay@ebizmarts-desk.zendesk.com

Comment: Pludin updated.but issue still showing on mobile when try to order.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SagePay plugin version. I had the same issue right after the upgrade to Magento 1.9.4.3. I contacted ebizmarts.com and they said this issue was fixed in the latest release of their plugin sage-pay-suite-pro-4.2.16. Please try updating, in our case, it fixed the problem and also helped resolving the issue which slow loading checkout page.

You can experience the same issue in Mailchimp plugin which also have been resolved in the latest release of their plugin.

Comment: Pludin updated. order placed from laptop but not from mobile.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this would not work on mobile. Please clean cache and re-test. Problem was related to something that is happening on the server-side not the client.

Comment: I tested again. order placed but success page not showing. Showing 404

Comment: 404 would suggest page not found. Please inspect your redirect url after payment if pointing to correct place.